# I deleted a question of mine, after noticing the answer was basically based on a faulty premise

Tags: discussion

I've just posted [a question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/why-do-iran-and-saudi-arabia-share-the-same-unique-age-of-majority), and deleted it after a little while, when I noticed that the answer was likely "bad information was written on Wikipedia".

However I'm *not* sure it really was as bad as it seems now, maybe someone more knowledgable than me would find something else instead.

So, I'm asking you: in this site would you prefer to have one question, whose answer *might likely* be "Wikipedia was wrong, ignore it", or not?

Comment: Please refrain from this language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question is based off a piece of faulty information, that's not actually a problem if the answers can identify that the information is faulty and can correct you on it.

So long as you're making a good faith attempt to look for a specific piece of knowledge, and you can communicate your needs well enough for people to answer your question, (and it's not a duplicate or off topic) then your question is just fine.

If the answer indeed is just that Wikipedia is wrong, then that's fine.  In fact, it's a very helpful question, because you can expect other people who have read that exact same Wikipedia to come along the question, and learn that the information is not actually true.