# I posted a question here, and it was just deleted. Are you insane?

Tags: discussion

If there was something inappropriate, you could have edited it.

But I know you'll just delete this too.

[I deleted a question of mine, after noticing the answer was basically based on a faulty premise](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1517/i-deleted-a-question-of-mine-after-noticing-the-answer-was-basically-wikipedia?noredirect=1#comment2366_1517)

Comment: Nice people keep alive the pleasure of hearing bad language on a stage. http://spiritroombook.blogspot.com/2005/11/nice-people.html

Answer (score 6):

1. I deleted it for profanity.
2. Absent the profanity, there was no content, even in the meta.
3. Sam I Am is a better person than I am.
4. Whether or not I am insane is unrelated to my actions in this question.